Movie scene replicated in Simpsons // city sightseeing drive with Fat Tony. "Camera" pointing up to the sky
I remember a scene from The Simpsons but I can not find it. For sure it was used in some well known movie before, you will know it.
I think it was a Bart in a car with Fat Tony with his guys cruising trough Springfield with camera mostly aiming to the sky, so we could mostly see trees, electricity cables, traffic lights etc. And some chilling music in the background (I guess same as in original movie scene) with the slow cuts as they traveled.
Cool scene, I mean really this wasn't a traditional scene from the Simpsons.
I am sorry, I can barely describe it better.
If you can remember more, please share it with me.
I would like to find the original or at least Simpsons version of the scene.

Sounds like the parody of the Sopranos opening sequence from the episode The Mook, the Chef, the Wife and Her Homer but I'm having trouble finding the right clip

Exactly it was that scene, with Sopranos, Some guy posted it as an answer,  but post got deleted, so I couldnt accept it after 4m time interval.
Thanks a lot to both of you guys.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UcvSVXlJglg

Ha, that was me, I deleted it because I think I got the wrong Simpsons video! Maybe someone else can find the right Simpsons video and answer :-)

Hahaha thanks a lot, just repost it again, maybe with my link and I will accept it as an answer :)
I also wanted to mention Ralph with a dog in the description, but I wasn't sure if it was in that scene.
I laughed so loud when hearing the music, thanks a lot one more time :D
Brother needs to make a video from our city, I was trying to to find this scene to show him, what can he do :)

It is a parody of The Sopranos opening theme.
For reference, the scene from The Simpsons


 (20 seconds in)
The opening theme from The Sopranos


 (6 seconds in, after HBO Entertainment Card)

user568458 was first but anyway thanks a lot :)
